# Instantiation object C#

Tags: c#, instantiation

```
Dude car = new dude(name="honda", year=1998);

Dude park = new Dude(name="blah", year=1996);

car=park;
```

I'm new to OOP, I see sometimes that these reference variables are set equal to each other even though it has different values. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. Can any explain why you would set an object equal to each other?

Comment: It would help if you'd use *actual* code instead of pseudo-code. And you're not setting one *object* equal to another; you're setting the value of one variable to be equal to the value of another variable - those values are *references* to objects, not objects themselves (assuming `Dude` is a class).

Comment: why would you set a variable equal to another variable? This is really not a very good question at all

Comment: Programming may not be for you... =)  J/K...  i think you need to think about your question AFTER you've written an application.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. You might get farther if you imagine a real world scenario and create some hypothetical API's. In your current example, the object prevoiusly referenced by car is no longer reachable and will be garbage collected.

Comment: thank you all for taking the time to further explain this !

Answer (score 5):

I'm gonna assume `Dude` is a class, not a struct.

> Can any explain why you would set an object equal to each other?

You're not setting "an object equal to each other".

You have two **variables**, `car` and `park`, each capable of *pointing to* **objects** of type `Dude`.

You then create a new `Dude` named "honda" and make the variable `car` point to it. You do something similar for `park`.

What the last line does is make the `car` variable point to the same object as `park`.
Now you have two variables pointing to a dude named "blah", and no variables pointing to the dude named "honda".

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a distinction between "object" and "variable". What we have here is two *objects* of type `Dude` - the first initialized with "honda" and 1998, the second with "blah" and 1996. These are objects, allocated in memory, and with all the logic involved in that class.

Now, you also have two *variables*. The first named "car", the second "park". At first, the variable "car" which originally points to the "honda" object, and the variable "park" which points at the "blah" object.

Your third line changes the assignment, so now both "car" and "park" point to the "blah" object, and no variable points to the "honda" object. Now regardless of whether you access `car.name` or `park.name`, you'll get the same value from the same object. The unreferenced object will eventually be picked up by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the objects equal to one another, you're setting *one* equal to the other. The assignment operator (`=`) sets the left side equal to the right side, losing the value of whatever was on the left before that line.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be of primitive types, like `int` or instances of `class`es, pointing to `object`s, like `String`. You might assign the value of a variable to another variable which can be useful in numerous cases. For instance you might have a `class` called `User`, which has a `username` field. When somebody logs in, he enters the `username` and password and you would like to modify the state of a `User` object so its `string` field (which is also an `object`) called `username` holds the `username` you have typed in. Later you can get the `username` of the `object`, because its field will hold the `username` entered as a value.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `car = park;` the initial value of `car` is lost forever since nothing is *pointing to* it and it will be collected by garbage collector to clear your memory. Now two variables are *pointing to* the same value of your object `park`. Why would you want two variables to point to the same object, you ask? Well, I can't think of the great example at the moment, but maybe you want to initialize the new object on the same variable (for example because you like the name of the variable) and you also want to keep your old object. In that case you need other object of the same type pointing to your instance before creating a `new` object. This way you won't lose the reference to an object and it won't be lost forever.